# Integrating Microsoft Office Communicator 2007 R2 - Samples?

Tags: c#, wpf, office-communicator

Basically, I can't seem to find any good resources out there for examples. I attempted to download a couple of msi from microsoft.com, and one of them included isntalling a solution file (.sln), but when I open the solution I can't actually compile the application.

Basically, what do I need to actually get started with getting the necessary libraries and sample code?

Answer (score 0):

A good resource to get started is the Programming for Unified Communications book - this covers R2 quite well. Check out the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840616/using-ucma-3-0-to-build-an-ocs-im-bot-where-do-i-start) for a bit more detail